# Is there anything like absolute continuity with respect to the sup of a class of measures?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $P$ and $Q$ be probability measures on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{X})$.  Then, we say that $P$ is dominated by (or absolutely continuous with respect to) $Q$, in symbols $Q \, \triangleright \, P$, if for all $B \in \mathcal{X}$ we have that if $Q(B)=0$, then also $P(B)=0$.

Now, let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\{Q_t,t \in K\}$ be a class of probability measures on $(X, \mathcal{X})$. Does the formula 
$$
\textbf{(1)} \hspace{5em} Q(B):=\sup_{t\in K}Q_t(B), \quad  B \in \mathcal{X},                 
$$

define a probability measure? If not, is there any notion similar to domination of $P$ by an object $Q$ defined as in $\textbf{(1)}$?

Comment: $Q$ need not be countably additive.

Comment: So it is not enough to say that $K$ is compact to claim $\sup_{t\in K}Q_t(\cup_{i\geq 1}B_i)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\sup_{t\in K}Q_t(B_i)$, where $B_i$'s are disjoint sets, right?

Comment: Would some "continuity" assumption on the map $t\mapsto Q_t$ help in exchanging $\sup$ and sum? I'm thinking to  something like "the latter map is continuous w.r.t. the Euclidean metric and the total variation metric". I was looking for conditions that allow to exchange integrals and suprema, and continuity seems to play a role, but I must say I have no clear understanding of that yet.

Comment: No, even such assumptions won't make it countably additive.

Comment: OK. Though, $Q$ would still be a finitely additive measure, right?

Comment: No, finite additivity also can fail. Spremum and additivity don't go well  with each other. The basic reason is $a \vee c+b \vee d \neq (a+b) \vee (c+d)$.